# DevOps release From QA to PRODUCTION

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I have two environment one is qa and other is production as general. But production is move from qa it is actually maps to same artifacts. So it is not that the qa is move to production. We are release by choosing a particular pr . So my question is, how can we marge code from perticular qa branch to master branch and release that master?

[image: All pipelines]

Comment: You should be releasing the **same** set of artifacts to every environment.

Comment: @DanielMann: Yes same artifacts we use

Answer (score 2):

If i understand you correctly, I think you need to add an artifacts filter to you production stage. Please check below screenshot.

As below screenshot showing, you can click the **Pre-deployment conditions** of prod stage and specifically add the artifacts filter to master branch. So that prod stage will only be triggered when the artifacts is released from master branch. If you want prod stage is deployed after stage qa, You can also **select trigger** to after stage.

[image]

With above artifact filters set to master, Whenever a PR is merged to master branch, it will trigger your build pipeline to build master branch(you need to enable CI for your build pipeline, please refer to below pic). Then when the artifacts from master is released, it will trigger production stage to deploy.
[image]